# É pessoível realizar consultas em uma tabela que não esta mapeada pelo Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, relacionamento, hql

Gostaria de listar dados de uma tabela que não esta mapeada pelo Hibernate; ou seja tenho uma tabela mapeda Endity e pelo Id dela quero relalizar uma busca em uma tabela no meu banco de dados que não é uma entity. Isso é possível?

Answer (score 0):

Sim é possível, basta realizar uma query nativa e a partir de uma entidade que é mapeada pelo Hibernante fazer este mapeamento.